# Postfix delivery retry fails if relay's IP was not found earlier

Tags: postfix

My Postfix daemon sometimes keeps a day's mail in its queue with errors like

```
15F0C64ADD     7422 Fri Sep  9 07:59:31  monnier@iro.umontreal.ca
(delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.teksavvy.com type=AAAA: Host not found, try again)
                                     monnier@iro.umontreal.ca
```

Thing is: `host smtp.teksavvy.com` gives me perfectly valid IP address.  The above message is due to an earlier problem (DSL connection down, typically) that was fixed hours ago.  `postqueue -f` does not help.  If I stop and restart the Postfix daemon, things do clear up, however.

How can I get Postfix to clear up the queue without manual intervention (and more quickly than at the end of the day), other than by forcing constant stops&restarts?

In [Delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/626249), the user runs `postqueue -f` when he reconnects to the network, but in my case the machine is always up and has "always" access to the network (obviously, except for when there's a problem upstream), so it would not know when to run `postqueue -f`.

In any case, running `postqueue -f` does not help: those email stay in the queue with the same "Host or domain name not found" error, even though the transient DNS error has been fixed long ago.  Should I report it as a Postfix bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found](http://serverfault.com/questions/626249/delivery-temporarily-suspended-host-or-domain-name-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the problem in my case turned out to be that Postfix is setup to run in a chroot (this is standard Postfix setup in Debian testing) and that the `/etc/resolv.conf` file in the chroot was not automatically kept in sync with the main one.  I fixed the problem by installing the `resolvconf` package (which runs the hooks that were expected to be used to keep the file in sync).